# How to deploy to ACS depending on branch from Travis

Tags: travis-ci

The .travis.yml file I have errors on line 25 where on: branch: master the exact error is

[x] syntax error: (): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 25 column 5

Im trying to make two different deployments based on the branch im pushing to.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- 10.8.0
cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules
services:
  - mongodb
  - docker
before_install:
  - pip install --user awscli
  - export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
install:
  - npm install
before_script:
  - npm run lint
script:
  - npm run test
deploy:
  # Production Deploy if we push to master
- eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
- docker build -t production-my-api .
- docker tag production-my-api:latest 989002346127.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production-my-api:latest
- docker push 989002346127.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production-my-api:latest
  on:
    branch: master
  # Develop Deploy if we push to develop
- eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
- docker build -t develop-my-api .
- docker tag develop-my-api:latest 989002346127.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/develop-my-api:latest
- docker push 989002346127.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/develop-my-api:latest
  on:
    branch: develop
env:
  global:
  - secure: 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
  - secure: 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
```

Comment: That's just not valid YAML, you can't switch from array to object half way through defining it.

Comment: Changing the question invalidates the error message. The answer doesn't actually help someone with that error message. If you've solved the problem, I'd recommend deleting.

Answer (score -1):

deploy_production.sh

```
   #!/bin/bash
    # Deploy to develop
    echo "Deploying to ACS"
    $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
    docker build -t develop-my-api .
    docker tag develop-my-api:latest 989002346127.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/develop-my-api:latest
    docker push 989002346127.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/develop-my-api:latest
```

and dont forget to change the  permissions chmod +x deploy_production.sh